# Simple code implementing vaapi decoding with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been looking at hwdecode-demos from Splitted-Desktop Systems
to learn how to use vaapi hardware accelerated decoding with ffmpeg.

As I'm not begginer programmer, I think haven't got it all right.

It would be great if someone woud be so nice to write simple notes
how to set up and use functions to get avcodec_decode_video done
with vaapi.

I know that it has to do something with struct *vaapi_context and
some functions - get_format. get_buffer, release_buffer - but I
can't figgure how to make that work with some simple ffmpeg api
like that one @ dranger.com/ffmpeg/